# Matching 2 arrays by ids (user[ user id as a key] to orders[value of orders ids array ])

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, functional-programming

I have an array of "users" and an array of "orders". 
I want to list all order_ids for each user_id.

```
var users = {
    0: {
        user_id: 111,
        user_name: "user111",
        isActive: 0
    },
    1: {
        user_id: 112,
        user_name: "use112",
        isActive: 1
    },
    2: {
        user_id: 113,
        user_name: "use113",
        isActive: 0
    },
    ...
}; 

var orders = {  
    888: {
        order_id: 888, 
        user_id: 111
    }, 
    889: {
        order_id: 889, 
        user_id: 111
    }, 
    890: {
        order_id: 890, 
        user_id: 113
    }
};
```

What is the best practice (in terms of efficiancy) to get me this result  of 
user_ids (user_id as a key) to orders (value of orders ids array):

```
result = {
    111: [ 888, 889 ],
    113: [ 890 ]
};
```

Using the "user" Object/array is a must, since my user variable is a filtered user list, and the userToOrder array should fetch all order_ids of some specific users and create a new object from it.

- No for loops, just pure es6 functionality.
- Trying to avoid the `.forEach()` for that practice unless it's impossible.
- no loadash answers unless theres a "vanilla es6" example.

These were my final tries, without any success:

```
let userToOrdersArray = users.map( function(user) {

    /*Object.values(orders).reduce((newObj, orderData) => {
        newObj[user.user_id][] = orderData.order_id;
    }, {});*/

    Object.values(orders).filter(function(orderData) {
        return (orderData.user_id === user.user_id); 
    });

});

console.log(userToOrdersArray);
```

Comment: what about user `112`?

Comment: You should know that those numeric keys you're using get converted to strings. I would suggest looking at [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) as it was specifically designed for this kind of data and these tasks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method.

```js
var users = {
  111: {
    user_id: 111,
    user_name: "user111",
    isActive: 0
  },
  112: {
    user_id: 112,
    user_name: "use112",
    isActive: 1
  },
  113: {
    user_id: 113,
    user_name: "use113",
    isActive: 0
  },
};
var orders = {
  888: {
    order_id: 888,
    user_id: 111
  },
  889: {
    order_id: 889,
    user_id: 111
  },
  890: {
    order_id: 890,
    user_id: 113
  }
};


// get all property values
var res = Object.values(orders)
  // iterate over values
  .reduce(function(obj, { user_id, order_id }) { // extract  properios using Destructuring feature
    // check user id present in users array
    if (user_id in users) {
      // define array for ids if not defined previously
      obj[user_id] = obj[user_id] || [];
      // push value to array
      obj[user_id].push(order_id);
    }
    // return object
    return obj;
    // set initial value as object
  }, {})

console.log(res)
```

Comment: Not exactly "purely functional" - your reducer is mutating the accumulator in place (`  obj[user_id] = obj[user_id] || [];
  obj[user_id].push(order_id);`), instead of returning a new value (new object).

Comment: But it's not filtered following the users object.

Comment: @mbojko :  it's not mutating, if it's defined it's just re-assigning or it will assign a new array as value

Comment: `push()` is mutating.

Comment: @mbojko :  yes he want to group them together

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming here that for the `users` object, the key is always equal to the `user_id` property.

```js
const users = {
  111: {
    user_id: 111,
    user_name: "user111",
    isActive: 0
  },
  112: {
    user_id: 112,
    user_name: "use112",
    isActive: 1
  },
  113: {
    user_id: 113,
    user_name: "use113",
    isActive: 0
  },
};

const orders = {
  888: {
    order_id: 888,
    user_id: 111
  },
  889: {
    order_id: 889,
    user_id: 111
  },
  890: {
    order_id: 890,
    user_id: 113
  }
};

const groupOrdersByUsers = (usersArr, ordersArr) => usersArr.map(id => ({[id]: ordersArr.filter(({user_id}) => user_id == id)}));

console.log(groupOrdersByUsers(Object.keys(users), Object.values(orders)));
```

Comment: you are right sir! Im just not sure if your answer is the more efficient one, or the other option mentioned in the post comments (using an if statement).

Comment: ohh, woops my bad, the right user id is the one inside the "user row" (user.user_id)

Comment: The most efficient would be most likely the good old "for" loops. Not very pretty, though. (To have both, it'll be best to do that SQL side, this is the stuff SQL lives for...)

Answer (score 1):

## This should do the trick

```js
const users = {
    0: {
        user_id: 111,
        user_name: "user111",
        isActive: 0
    },
    1: {
        user_id: 112,
        user_name: "use112",
        isActive: 1
    },
    2: {
        user_id: 113,
        user_name: "use113",
        isActive: 0
    },
}

  
const orders = {  
  888: {
    order_id: 888, 
    user_id: 111
  }, 
  889: {
    order_id: 889, 
    user_id: 111
  }, 
  890: {
    order_id: 890, 
    user_id: 113
  }
}

const getOrderIdsFromUserId = (user_id, orders) =>
  Object.values(orders).reduce(
    (order_ids, order) => 
      order.user_id===user_id ? [order.order_id,...order_ids] : order_ids,
    []
  )

const f = (users, orders) =>
  Object.values(users).reduce(
    (y, user) => ({
      ...y,
      [user.user_id]: getOrderIdsFromUserId(user.user_id, orders),
    }),
    {},
  )

console.log(f(users, orders))
```